# Locking the screen on Ubuntu 22.04 leads to spontaneous restart

Tags: usb, hard-drive, lock-screen, reboot

This is a problem I've been plagued by for a while now. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo V330-15IKB laptop. I use an external hard-drive connected to it. The hard-drive is a TOSHIBA USB 3.5-HDD 1 TB hard-drive.

Most of the time, when I "screen lock" my device -- with the external hard-drive connected -- I see after a while that the laptop has restarted. So, I tried disconnecting the external hard-drive and got the same result.

The screen lock has become extremely unreliable! I don't know what is causing this.

Please help!

Edit 1: I tried locking the laptop after quitting Nautilus. It remained locked without restarting. However, when I tried the same while charging, it once again restarted spontaneously.
I, generally, leave my Nautilus and Thunderbird 'on' while locked.

Edit 2: Even though I have the 'ignore-lid-switch' tweak turned on, closing the lid results in completely unreliable behaviour - as in, it restarts sometimes and sometimes, it doesn't.